# Solve differential equation via successive approximations (contraction mapping principle)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, contraction-operator

I'm working on a problem (self study) to solve the differential equation $$
\frac{dx}{dt} = tx^2 + x^3
$$
using successive approximations within a neighborhood interval of $\delta < 1/5$. I'm given that the initial condition is $x(0) = 1$.

Toward this end, I've defined the contraction map $$
\Phi(f)(t) \, \triangleq \, 1 + \int_0^t \left\{
s (f(s))^2 + (f(s))^3
\right\} ds.
$$

Let $f_{i+1} = \Phi(f_i)$ and $f_0(t) = 1$.

Two things puzzle me:

1. Repeatedly solving the integrals to determine $f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots$, etc. and finding a pattern seems tedious / difficult since the polynomials blow up in degree. Is there an easier route here?
2. How does the given neighborhood radius $\delta < 1/5$ figure into the solution? Or is it simply the interval for which the resulting solution is valid?

Comment: What makes you think that the IVP has a closed form solution? Mathematica gives an expression in the implicit form (too long for a comment), in terms of the derivatives of the [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).

Comment: It was a problem in a text book so I thought it would have a closed form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Contractractivity on a rectangular domain

To apply the fixed-point theorem one needs to fix a domain for the ODE and determine the Lipschitz constant there. In the most simple case the domain is rectangular, $[-δ,δ]\times[1-M,1+M]$. The space for the Banach fixed-point theorem is then the set of continuous functions $X={\cal C}([-δ,δ]\to[1-M,1+M])$.

First one has to guarantee that $Φ$ maps $X$ into itself, that is, $|x(t)-1|<M\implies |Φ(x)(t)-1|<M$ for $|t|<δ$. Then you can compute the Lipschitz constant $L$ over that rectangle and put as additional condition that the contraction constant for $Φ$ is contracting, that is, $Lδ<1$, possibly by making $δ$ smaller.

The first condition is satisfied if
$$
|Φ(x)(t)-1|\le\int_0^t |sx(s)^2+x(s)^3|ds<\frac{δ^2}2(1+M)^2+δ(1+M)^3\overset{!}{\le} M.
$$
The last inequality can be transformed as
$$
\left(1+\fracδ{1+M}\right)^2\le 1+\frac{2M}{(1+M)^4}
\iff 
δ\le (1+M)\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2M}{(1+M)^4}}-1\right)
$$
The right side looks like

[image]

> so that this approach allows to choose $δ=\frac18$ with $M=0.5$.

The $x$-Lipschitz constant is the maximum over the $x$-derivative, thus $L=2δ(1+M)+3(1+M)^2=\frac38+\frac{27}4=7+\frac18$ so that actually $Lδ<1$ and the iteration converges on this set.

To reach higher values of $t$ one needs to consider other regions than the rectangular one, or even other integral equations for the iteration, like $1-x(t)^{-1}=\int_0^t(s+x(s))\,ds$ which will then also need a separate computation of the contraction condition for the fixed-point theorem.

---

#### Upper and lower bounds

To get better bounds for the solution, use estimates on the differential equation itself so that the solution of differential inequalities provides the bounds.

For $t>0$ the solution is increasing, so that for $t< δ\le \frac12$ we get $2t\le x(t)$ which gives a lower and upper bound for the solution
$$
2tx^2\le \dot x\le 2x^3\implies t^2\le 1-x(t)^{-1}\land 1-x(t)^{-2}\le 4t
\\~~\\
\implies \frac1{1-t^2}\le x(t)\le \frac1{\sqrt{1-4t}}
$$
which shows that the solution will diverge to infinity at some $t^*<1$, but not before $t=\frac14<t^*$. Zooming into the numerical solution gives $t^*>0.446$ as close estimate.
[image]

For $t<0$ the inverted relations hold as $x(t)>0$ by the uniqueness theorem, as the zero function is also a solution. Thus for $t<0$ $$ \frac1{1-t^2}\ge x(t)\ge \frac1{\sqrt{1-4t}}$$